# How to find the roots in a quadratic function in vertex form?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I have been assigned the task to express the vertex form quadratic function from  `2(x - (sqrt(2)/2))^2 - 3 - sqrt(2)` into the standard form and the x-intercept form. The vertex form, in my reference, is `f(x) = a(x-h)^2 + k.` How can I convert this into the standard form `f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c` and from there find the roots and find the root form `f(x) = a(x-r)(x-s)` where r and s are roots?

Answer (score 1):

While you can get it into standard form by using FOIL or the binomial theorem to square $(x-h)^2=x^2-2hx+h^2$, it's actually easier not to go through the standard form:

$$\begin{align}
a(x-h)^2+k&=0  \\ 
a(x-h)^2&=-k \\
(x-h)^2&=-k/a \\
x-h&=\pm\sqrt{-k/a}\\
x&=h\pm \sqrt{-k/a}
\end{align}.$$

Comment: Can you specify exactly how to determine the roots using this method? The form that I have is `f(x) = a(x-h)^2 + k`, not equivalent to zero.

Comment: The roots of a polynomial are where it equals $0$.

Answer (score 0):

To convert to "standard" form, expand and simplify.

To convert to "$x$-intercept" form, factorise as follows. We have $$2(x-\sqrt 2/2)^2-3-\sqrt 2=2(x-\sqrt 2/2)^2-\left(\sqrt{3+\sqrt2}\right)^2,$$ which is a difference of two squares and may be factorised by noting that $$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y).$$

Comment: How would you factorize like so? Isn't 2 multiplying `(x-sqrt(2)/2)^2`?

Comment: @ForrestZeng Yes, but you can write $2$ as $(\sqrt 2)^2$ as well. Do you now see how to proceed?